# CheckBoxList's checked selection not populating on page load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

On my aspx I have the following:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="MyCheckBoxList" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Then in the backend beofore loading I have this code:

```
var pq = from p in MyQuery select p.fullname;
```

then I do this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Users");

foreach (var p in pq)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { string.Format(p, p) });
}

MyCheckBoxList.DataSource = dt;
foreach (var checkedItem in this.MyCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>())
{
    checkedItem.Enabled = true;
    checkedItem.Selected = true;
}

MyCheckBoxList.DataBind();
```

It goes through all my checkboxlist items and sets the selected to true but when I check my .aspx, the check boxes are not checked. can you tell me what am I missing here?

Sorry  this was missing:

Comment: What you are doing with `pq ` and where you have written this `foreach` code?

Comment: you need to provide more details about your solution

Comment: @RahulSingh Sorry updated the code.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Please see updated. sorry forgot piece of code.

Comment: @AmeerKabeer - Still incomplete, in which event you are calling this? like `Page_Load` or something? Also, why you are filling the _DataTable_? You can directly assign the `pq ` to checkboxlist.

Comment: @RahulSingh  It is on page load. I tried without adding it to datatable I was unsuccessful.

Comment: @AmeerKabeer - And where is your call to _DataBind_ method?

Comment: @RahulSingh it was `MyCheckBoxList.DataBind();` that did not work either.

Comment: I think you need to create your checkboxes already with enabled/selected set and then set as datasource...instead of `new object[]` create a checkbox object with all properties you need.

Comment: @AmeerKabeer - Can you share the code where you have added that? I can't imagine that.

Comment: @RahulSingh added ..

Comment: @ElmerDantas you mean the order is incorrect?

Comment: yep! all I think the all properties should be set in your 'foreach'

Comment: @ElmerDantas can you elaborate on that or provide a snippet ?

Comment: you can see my answer or Rahul`s...that's should do what you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your solution to this

```
var pq = from p in MyQuery select p.fullname;
foreach (var p in pq)
{
    ListItem chkBox = new ListItem(p, p, true);
    chkBox.Selected = true;
    MyCheckBoxList.Items.Add(chkBox);  
}
```

(no databind needed)

I didn't test but should do what you want.

Comment: I see what you did here but this does not seem to work either.  Just to let you know the .fullname is a list of names that is all.

Comment: I see...create a list of names with Text and Value as `p` (fullname)...this should work o.O...are you using `IsPostBack`? (as we're talking about webforms)

Comment: `!IspostBack` ... not post back. Nothing is checked.

Comment: I mean `!IsPostBack` also wrote without `!` just to know if you're using it...just wondering how this is not working...really weird

Comment: you're definitely missing something...I just tested here and works properly

Comment: when I remove ! I get blank.

Comment: I just ask if you were using...not to remove! hahaha you're missing something my friend...try do figure out what it is. Here works perfectly. Here is a print => http://imgur.com/a/VHapM

Comment: my pq is an IQueryable<string>. I think that is where the problem is.

Comment: this made it work :) `List<string> pq = new List<string>(PersonQuery.Select(person => person.fullname));`

Comment: all you needed was to make sure the you have a list of the object you want to use. Keep it in mind ;-)

Comment: Thank you Elmer.. I posted my response just in case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that your`CheckBox` list is not binded and you are trying to set it's item values, you should first bind it and then call foreach. This should give you the expected output:-

```
var pq = from p in MyQuery select new { Name = p.fullname };
MyCheckBoxList.DataSource = pq ;
MyCheckBoxList.DataTextField = "Name";
MyCheckBoxList.DataValueField = "Name";
MyCheckBoxList.DataBind(); //You should call DataBind here.
foreach (var checkedItem in this.MyCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>())
{
    checkedItem.Enabled = true;
    checkedItem.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: @AmeerKabeer - What didn't worked? Have you taken the updated `pq` query?

Comment: Yes, nothing is selected from the list of names.

Comment: @AmeerKabeer - Are you doing this `select new { Name = p.fullname };`? That's important. Also, what exception you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any exception .. just the checkboxes are NOT checked. I did exactly as you said.

Comment: @AmeerKabeer - No you haven't. I have tested this code and its working fine. There is definitely something which you're missing.

Comment: I don't know how to send you a screenshot but I copied your code and pasted there and still my checkboxes are NOT checked.

Comment: I sent the screen shots to your email.

Comment: @AmeerKabeer - No I din't get, you can post it on http://imgur.com and share the url.

Comment: my PQ is an IQueryable<string>.. I believe that is where the issue is.

Comment: @AmeerKabeer - How come it is `IQueryable<string>` when we have used `new { Name = p.fullname };` that means you have not used my code.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I can't up vote or I would have your response.. I posted my response just in case.

Comment: @AmeerKabeer - Np! Maybe in future you can :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with IQueryable .. so doing this fixed it.. Per Elmer Dantas answer.

```
 var pq = new List<string>(PersonQuery.Select(person => person.fullname));
                    foreach (var chkBox in pq.Select(p => new ListItem(p, p, true))) {
                        chkBox.Selected = true;
                        MyCheckBoxList.Items.Add(chkBox);
                    }
```